# Fourier transform of Airy function

Tags: fourier-transform, bessel-functions, airy-functions

I am looking for the Fourier transform of the Airy function $\left(\dfrac{2J_1(x)}{x}\right)^2$ where $J_1$ is the Bessel function of the first kind of order one.

Thank you.

Comment: That is not the Airy function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which of the [Airy functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AiryFunctions.html) this is related to, but Wolfram Alpha and Mathematica give the result

$$\mathcal{F}_x\left[\left(\frac{2 J_1(x)}{x}\right)^2\right](\omega)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \omega\, (\theta(-\omega-2)-\theta(\omega-2)+2 \theta(\omega)-1)\, G_{2,2}^{2,0}\left(\frac{\omega^2}{4}|
\begin{array}{c}
 1,2 \\
 -\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)\tag{1}$$

in terms of the [MeijerG function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeijerG-Function.html) (see [WolframAlpha evaluation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=FourierTransform%5B%282%20BesselJ%5B1%2C%20x%5D%2Fx%29%5E2%2C%20x%2C%20%5C%5BOmega%5D%5D)) which expands in terms of [Elliptic E](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheSecondKind.html) and [Elliptic K](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html) functions as

$$\mathcal{F}_x\left[\left(\frac{2 J_1(x)}{x}\right)^2\right](\omega)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{4 \sqrt{2} \left(\left(\omega^2+4\right)\, E\left(1-\frac{\omega^2}{4}\right)-2 \omega^2\, K\left(1-\frac{\omega^2}{4}\right)\right)}{3 \pi^{3/2}} & -2<\omega<2 \\
 0 & \text{Otherwise} \\
\end{array}\right.\tag{2}$$

where the Fourier transform is defined as

$$\mathcal{F}_x[f(x)](\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\, e^{i \omega x}\,dx\,.\tag{3}$$

---

The figure below illustrates a plot of the right-side of formula (2) above.

[image: plot of the right-side of formula (2)]